# Exit full screen on Angular when starting with full screen

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, google-chrome

When starting chrome with full screen, exiting full screen on angular does not work.

html:

```
<hello name="{{ name }}"></hello>
<a href="https://angular-go-full-screen-f11-key.stackblitz.io" target="_blank" style="display: block;">
  Open in new window
</a>
<button (click)="openFullscreen()">Go full screen</button>
<button (click)="closeFullscreen()">Exit full screen</button>
```

ts:

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, Inject, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) {}
  elem;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.elem = document.documentElement;
  }

  openFullscreen() {
    if (this.elem.requestFullscreen) {
      this.elem.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      /* Firefox */
      this.elem.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      this.elem.webkitRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (this.elem.msRequestFullscreen) {
      /* IE/Edge */
      this.elem.msRequestFullscreen();
    }
  }

  /* Close fullscreen */
  closeFullscreen() {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      this.document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (this.document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      /* Firefox */
      this.document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (this.document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      /* Chrome, Safari and Opera */
      this.document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    } else if (this.document.msExitFullscreen) {
      /* IE/Edge */
      this.document.msExitFullscreen();
    }
  }
}
```

This is [stackblitz sample.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-go-full-screen-f11-key?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

When opening the page above (and "open in new window"), the "Go full screen" and "Exit full screen" buttons work.

But when opening this page with full screen option as below, the "Exit full screen" button does not work.

`chrome.exe --start-fullscreen https://angular-go-full-screen-f11-key.stackblitz.io`

Why "Exit full screen" does not work when starting with full screen mode? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a difference between a user-agent initiated "Go fullscreen" action (e.g. starting with `--start-fullscreen` flag or entering fullscreen using `F11` and the Fullscreen-API initiated `requestFullscreen" call.

When opening the DevTools and adding a Live-expression to watch `document.fullscreenElement`, you can see, that this is not set when using `F11` or `--start-fullscreen` but it is set, when using the Fullscreen-API.
`document.exitFullscreen()` will only work when `document.fullscreenElement` is set.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/fullscreenElement

A possible solution could be to depend on a URL-parameter and toggle to fullscreen inside your component-logic in case it is set?

See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-go-full-screen-f11-key-xiq6va?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts for a demo that launches fullscreen.

Comment: Thanks for response. But I got `Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.` error.

Comment: This might be an issue, also depending on the browser. On Chrome / Windows, entering fullscreen when loading the StackBlitz works as expected for me (when the tab is in foreground), Firefox blocks it.
I made some adjustments to the StackBlitz which may be helpful to tell users how they can leave fullscreen mode. To check this, I tried to determine how the fullscreen-mode was entered (via Fullscreen API or via the browser itself) and show an according hint to the user depending on the context.
See https://angular-go-full-screen-f11-key-xiq6va.stackblitz.io/

Comment: Is there still something missing from my answer / comments?

Comment: Sorry for late response. Unfortunately my app will be used in touch screen and F11 can not be used.

Comment: Then you might simply change the hint for the user to tell him what to do: https://superuser.com/questions/1146929/how-to-exit-chrome-full-screen-on-a-win-tablet